# Transação em bancos diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Em uma determinada parte do sistema preciso fazer o controle de transação, porém essa operação envolve tabelas que estão em banco de dados diferentes.

Fiz um teste efetuando inserções em duas tabelas em bancos diferentes e ao final delas efetuando um `rollback`, como era esperado essa operação falhou, o `rollback` aconteceu apenas na primeira tabela.

Existe alguma forma de controlar as transações dado esse cenário?

***Observações:***

- Estou utilizando Laravel.
- Os dois bancos são mysql

O teste que eu fiz continha o seguinte código:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

Aluno::create(['nome' =>   'teste']);

Professor::create(['nome'  => 'teste2' ]);

DB::rollback();
```

Em cada model eu setei uma `connection` diferente.

Comment: Os dois bancos estão no mesmo servidor (comunicam-se entre si)? A transação geralmente é gerenciada por conexão, se vocÊ tem duas conexões diferentes acredito que você precisará tratá-las isoladamente e só comitar uma se a outra for commitada com sucesso (o rollback também seria feito para cada conexão)

Comment: os bancos estão no mesmo servidor, porém são duas conexões diferentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como! Nem se o seu usuário tiver permissões em ambos os bancos e estiverem no mesmo servidor! O que você pode fazer neste caso é trabalhar com duas conexões diferentes e tratá-las separadamente conforme a necessidade. Segue um link de referência.. Espero que ajude! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239810/multiple-database-and-transactions